# List PDF files with missing metadata

Tags: awk, ls

I have had a few tasks where I needed to make reports on file changes on directories from different servers and have managed to make the reports using simple Unix commands. I used:

```
ls -R -lT /Volumes/www/subdir/ | awk '{if ($7=="" ) print $0; else print $11";"$7"/"$8"/"$10;}' > /Users/[username]/Desktop/output.txt
```

Now I need to make a report of all the PDF files that are missing metadata. I was wondering if there is a way (much like my current method) to check the metadata of a file and output only the ones with missing metadata. I want to pipe the ls results to a file so that i can import the data to Excel. In my other reports I used awk to format the ls output so that it could be imported into Excel.

This operation will be done on a Mac and prefer to use built-in commands over installing, as I do not have admin rights to install software on office hardware.

**Update:**
This report will be modified to not only report on PDFs but I foresee having to report on other file types in the future. So a report may search one or many file types.

The meta data I need to check for right now is:

- title
- author
- subject
- keywords

I have managed to list out a files metadata using:

```
mdls [path to file]
```

This results in a list of all the meta data. I tested it with a pdf with meta filled out and one without the meta filled out. I noticed with the missing meta data it is not returning null but rather not listing the meta key at all.

Something i'm currently trying is:

```
mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/web/ "kMDItemAuthors == ''"
```

How could I use this data to filter the output of `ls`

**Update:**
I managed to get a report that lists all pdfs, by using the following:

```
ls -R -lT [server directory path] | grep ".[file extension]" | awk '{print $11";"$7"/"$8"/"$10;}' > [output file path]
```

One of the side effects of this is that i'm losing the recursive property from the ls. Still working on this.

I also need to find a way to filter only the ones that are missing the required metadata. I have also been advised I need to also make a report of the PDFs that have all the metadata as well. I have tried using this current command and piping the output to mdfind first then to awk but I must be missing something.

Comment: Can you specify "missing metadata" some more? If you want to check if a PDF has no metadata at all (which I'm not sure is allowed by the spec) you could grep binary for the PDF/XMP tags. For a higher level check, try with `pdfinfo` which is part of `xpdf` which might or might not be bundled in Mac OSX, not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Use [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

To print full path (`-T -FilePath`) to all files with extension `pdf` recursively (`-r`) in `/search/path` that have either of your specified metadata empty, use:

```
exiftool -T -FilePath \
         -if '$FileTypeExtension eq "pdf"' \
         -if '(not $Title) or (not $Author) or (not $Subject) or (not $Keywords)' \
         -r /search/path
```

Customize the command to suit your future needs.

Comment: Is this included with the default OS X? we are not permitted to install anything if its not included.

Comment: This is a perl script, no "installation" required.

Comment: I will test this in the morning when i have access to the mac again. at this time of day I don't have access to it.

Comment: The error i get is exiftool: command not found

Comment: The office mac doesn't have exiftool

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more generic, you'd have to create some program/script to do the checking for one file, and use `find(1)` to run it on each target in turn, something like:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -exec check \;
```

where you make sure that `check file` always returns success (0), and prints the name of the offending file as appropriate. Or tweak the above to just return success if the file is broken, and go:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -exec check \; -print
```